# Cannot force a line break after a row of images

Tags: html, css

In a blog post  (for the [Cooking Stackexchange blog](http://cooking.blogoverflow.com), so a normal WordPress instance with only a few plugins), I inserted three images, aligned to "left", and want them to take up their own row. I want the text to start below them.

No matter what I try, (I inserted the `<p>`, `<br>` and `<div>` tags you see in the code manually) the text starts on the same row as the images, looking terrible. What can I do?

[image: The wrong layout]

The code which produces the screenshot above:

```
<p> I expected a bigger difference between these 3 methods. The silicone mat browned the cookies a bit
less than the other methods – so it can provide a little insurance if
you’re afraid of burnt cookies. </p> 
<div><img class="wp-image-870 alignleft" style="margin-left: 2px; margin-right: 2px;" title="baking sheet cookies" src="http://cooking.blogoverflow.com/files/2012/08/IMG_3784-225x300.jpg" alt="Cookies baked on baking sheet" width="225" height="300" /><img class="wp-image-869 alignleft" style="margin-left: 2px; margin-right: 2px;" title="silpat cookies" src="http://cooking.blogoverflow.com/files/2012/08/IMG_3787-225x300.jpg" alt="" width="225" height="300" /><img class="alignleft size-medium wp-image-868" style="margin-left: 2px; margin-right: 2px;" title="parchment paper cookies" src="http://cooking.blogoverflow.com/files/2012/08/IMG_3790-225x300.jpg" alt="" width="225" height="300" /><br/></div>
&nbsp;
<p>I’m going to stick with parchment paper, because it offers one big
advantage over the bare sheet and silicone mat:
```

Comment: This is a purely css question and should better be moved to SO.

Answer (score 4):

You need to clear the float after the `<img />` to force `<div />` to properly calculate height.

To do that add `style="overflow:hidden;` to the opening `<div>` tag, so the updated code would look like this:

```
<p> I expected a bigger difference between these 3 methods. The silicone mat browned the cookies a bit less than the other methods &ndash; so it can provide a little insurance if you're afraid of burnt cookies. </p>

<div style="overflow:hidden;">
    <img class="wp-image-870 alignleft" style="margin-left: 2px; margin-right: 2px;" title="baking sheet cookies" src="http://cooking.blogoverflow.com/files/2012/08/IMG_3784-225x300.jpg" alt="Cookies baked on baking sheet" width="225" height="300" />
    <img class="wp-image-869 alignleft" style="margin-left: 2px; margin-right: 2px;" title="silpat cookies" src="http://cooking.blogoverflow.com/files/2012/08/IMG_3787-225x300.jpg" alt="" width="225" height="300" />
    <img class="alignleft size-medium wp-image-868" style="margin-left: 2px; margin-right: 2px;" title="parchment paper cookies" src="http://cooking.blogoverflow.com/files/2012/08/IMG_3790-225x300.jpg" alt="" width="225" height="300" />
</div>

<p>I'm going to stick with parchment paper, because it offers one big advantage over the bare sheet and silicone mat:</p>
```

You can find more details about floats here: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 1):

Add `clear:both` to the CSS styling for that division.

Also why not add a class for the images in that division, then you wont have to use the `style=""` inline styling, if you decide you want a margin of 3px in the future you just change it in your stylesheet rather than having to go back through all the previous posts.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead - don't need the clear, and the images will appear horizontally justified too:

```
<p>I expected a bigger difference between these 3 methods. The silicone mat browned the cookies a bit less than the other methods – so it can provide a little insurance if you’re afraid of burnt cookies.</p> 
<p style="text-align: center;"><img class="wp-image-870 alignleft" title="baking sheet cookies" src="http://cooking.blogoverflow.com/files/2012/08/IMG_3784-225x300.jpg" alt="Cookies baked on baking sheet" width="225" height="300" /><img class="size-medium wp-image-868 alignright" title="parchment paper cookies" src="http://cooking.blogoverflow.com/files/2012/08/IMG_3790-225x300.jpg" alt="" width="225" height="300" /><img class="wp-image-869" title="silpat cookies" src="http://cooking.blogoverflow.com/files/2012/08/IMG_3787-225x300.jpg" alt="" width="225" height="300" /></p>
<p>I’m going to stick with parchment paper, because it offers one big advantage over the bare sheet and silicone mat:</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Giv `p` a `min-width` to avoid very short orphans:

```
p {
    min-width: 10em;
}
```